# Implementing Dynamic Meter Tag in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, razor, meter

I'm working on a project where I wish to use dynamic meter bars to represent peoples progress towards goal. This would mean having a numeric goal value and numeric current balance towards that goal.

I have been unable to see any implementaion of this in a ASP.NET Application where a dynamic value is used to give a representation of the total and completed values.

I have tried using the below code but to now avail.

```
<meter value="Balance" min="0" max="Goal"></meter>
```

I was thinking of using a progress bar but my understanding is that this should only be used for measuring moving progress towards a goal which will be completed reasonabliy soon as would be the case with a software instilation or something of that nature.

If anyone can help I'd be greatful.

Comment: Using this `<meter>` element is not currently advisable as it is only supported by recent builds of Gecko and WebKit, IE 10 does not support it.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "dynamic value"? Do you mean programattically setting the `max=""` attribute from within your ASP.NET code, or from JavaScript? Note that the specification ( http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#the-progress-element ) states the `max=""` attribute accepts a numeric value, so the string "`Goal`" is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for that. Would it be more advisable to use the Progress tag instead then?

Comment: I'd just implement a progress bar by using Javascript to horizontally stretch a `<div>` or something similar. It's simple and works in every browser released in the past 15 years.

Comment: Have you thought about looking at the google guage chart? https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge

Comment: Thanks. I'll make sure to research them. At least I know a meter isn't a viable option. I need a bar representation so I'll go with a progress bar and save myself some work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly implement what I was looking for the below tutorial gave me what I needed to know. http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_ui_mvc_progressbar.ashx